# Train Question on Time Distance Speed

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been solving a question:
A train, after traveling 60 km, meets with an accident, and then proceeds at
$3\over 4$th of its former rate, and arrives at the terminus $40$ minutes late. Had the accident happened $25$ km further on, it would have arrived $10$
minutes sooner. Find the speed of the train and the total distance.

There are simpler ways to solve this problem, and the solution is available on lot of sites. The method that I chose is a bit lengthy; but I want to know where my method is going wrong, since that would help me understand where my concept is wrong.

My method: 
Let $T$ be the time it takes for the train to arrive in case no accidents happen.
Assume $S$ is the normal speed, $D$ is total distance.
Therefore, in case the accident happens after $60$ km, since it arrives $40$ minutes late, which is $40\over 60$ hour, we have

$$\begin{align}&T + {40\over 60} = {60\over S} + {{D-60}\over {3S/4}}\\[1.5ex]
\implies &T + {40\over 60} = {60\over S} + {4D\over 3S} - {240\over 3S}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Similarly, if the accident happened after $25$ km more, then the train would be $10$ minutes ($10\over 60$ hour) early. So now the train has covered $85$ km:

$$\begin{align}&T - {10\over 60} = {85\over S} + {D-85\over 3S/4}\\[1.5ex]
\implies &T - {10\over 60} = {85\over S} + {4D\over 3S} - {340\over 3S}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Solving $1$ and $2$
$$\begin{align}
&\implies& T - {10\over 60} &= {85\over S} + {4D\over 3S} - {340\over 3S}\tag2\\[1.5ex]
&\implies& T + {40\over 60} &= {60\over S} + {4D\over 3S} - {240\over 3S}\tag1\\[1.5ex]
&\implies& -{50\over 60} &= {25\over S} -{100\over 3S}\\[1.5ex]
&\implies& -{50\over 60} &= {75\over 3S} - {100\over 3S} \\[1.5ex]
&\implies&  {25\over 3S} &= {50\over 60}\end{align}$$

therefore $S = 10\,\mathrm{km\over hr}$. 
But the answer is $S = 50\,\mathrm{km\over hr}$.

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: In the second part, when it is meant 10 minutes sooner, it can't arrive sooner than when it normally arrives, because it's speed reduces across the journey, while it would normally be constant.  "10 minutes sooner" means $30$ minutes late I think. See if that gives you the answer?

Comment: Awesome..Yes you are correct 2nd equation would be T+30, its 10 mins early relative to 40 mins late, that solved the Problem. Thanks a lot. Appreciated.

Comment: That was a mistake while phrasing the problem. I suppose we all come across it sometime or the other.